# How to collect data from a bulk of core.async go channels?

Tags: clojure

How can I collect data from a bulk of `go` channels? I get `assert failed: <! used not in (go ...)` for the code below. I know why I get it, I'm asking what is the best way to consume from all channels.

```
(->> state :pods (map #(go [(pd/id %) 
    (<! (f/pod-metrics fleet %))])) (map <!) (into {}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/merge to merge your source channels into one and then use [`<!!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/%3C!!) to take val from it. Note that [`<!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/%3C!) can only be used inside a [`go`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/go) block.